# with links to lib in vs 2013 with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I have asked a question about this issue a day ago and was answered with a good solution. All the LNK errors were fixed except for one I can not figure out. Here is the LNK error:

```
    Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class cv::Ptr<class cv::FaceRecognizer> __cdecl cv::createLBPHFaceRecognizer(int,int,int,int,double)" (?createLBPHFaceRecognizer@cv@@YA?AV?$Ptr@VFaceRecognizer@cv@@@1@HHHHN@Z) referenced in function __catch$?getFace@@YAXXZ$0 C:\Users\Parker\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\PAD_visualEngine\PAD_visualEngine\Source.obj  PAD_visualEngine
```

I have added the include directory and additional library directory in the project properties. 
I have even added the build directory in the path and separated the debug libraries with the release libraries. Here are the lines of codes I added to fix the previous link problems:

```
    #pragma comment (lib, "opencv_core248d.lib")
    #pragma comment (lib, "opencv_highgui248d.lib")
    #pragma comment (lib, "opencv_imgproc248d.lib")
    #pragma comment (lib, "opencv_video248d.lib")
    #pragma comment (lib, "opencv_features2d248d.lib")
    #pragma comment (lib, "opencv_photo248d.lib")
    #pragma comment (lib, "opencv_ts248d.lib")
    #pragma comment (lib, "opencv_stitching248d.lib")
    #pragma comment (lib, "opencv_superres248d.lib")
    #pragma comment (lib, "opencv_videostab248d.lib")
    #pragma comment (lib, "opencv_objdetect248d.lib")
    #pragma comment (lib, "opencv_nonfree248d.lib")
    #pragma comment (lib, "opencv_gpu248d.lib")
    #pragma comment (lib, "opencv_flann248d.lib")
    #pragma comment (lib, "opencv_calib3d248d.lib")
    #pragma comment (lib, "opencv_features2d248d.lib")
    #pragma comment (lib, "opencv_imgproc248d.lib")
    #pragma comment (lib, "opencv_legacy248d.lib")
    #pragma comment (lib, "opencv_ml248d.lib")
    #pragma comment (lib, "opencv_ocl248d.lib")
```

Thank you in advance! and also I added all of the libraries to the #pragma functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LBPHFaceRecognizer` is implemented in `contrib` module. Add the following pragma:

```
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_contrib248d.lib")
```